# Generate token for an action

Tags: python, security, token

I need to generate a token that will allow someone to do a unique action.
The difficulty is that nobody must find this token and do the action of someone else. Using python i would like to know if generating a random token is enough or not ? Can someone tell me what is necessary for generating a strong token that can't be found easily

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you give some context? What do you mean with "can't be found easily"? Should a user of your online service (if you work on one) not be able to see a token? Or should it not be in memory so it can't be found if someone physically takes your pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is have a code that generates a random 32 bit string from just letters (Upper case and lower case) and numbers and save it in the DB with a expire time (A few hours will be enough).

This way even if the "hacker" starts brute force by the time he is even close, the token will be expired and he will have to start from the beggening.

**Note:**

If you want to make it even stronger you can also use special characters in your token.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> def generate_key(number=20):  
>     result = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(number))  
>     return result
> ```

md5(username + password_hash + a_random_string) + generate_key(). I think it's strong as you expected. Actually I usually use generate_key only. I find it strong enough.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses.
In fact i can't have an expire time.
This is something someone can buy, we give him a token and with this token he will be able to do an action. So i can't use a expiry time. I think i need something very strong and unique.

```
inascii.hexlify(os.urandom(number))
```

Can this code hold uniqueness ?